# How to depend the generic of a List to the implementing Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

At the moment I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Entity 
{
    private final String id; 
    private String name;
    protected List <CustomerListener> listenerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addEntityListener (CustomerListener listener)
    {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name; 
        listenerList.forEach(listener) -> 
        {
            listener.nameChanged(name);
        }
    }
    //Imagine a constructor and some getter ... ;) 
}
```

```
public class Customer extends Entity
{
    private String company;
    private String businessUnit;
    private String position;

    public void setCompany (String company)
    {
        this.company = company; 
        listenerList.forEach(listener) -> 
        {
            listener.companyChanged(company);
        }
    }
    //Imagine  a construtor and some more getter and setter.
}
```

The following Interface Instances are stored in the ArrayList above:

```
public abstract interface EntityListener
{
    void nameChanged (String name);
}
```

```
public interface CustomerListener extends EntityListener
{
    void businessUnitChanged (String businessUnit);
    void companyChanged (String company);
    void positionChanged (String position);
}
```

My intention was, that I want to handle every value change to a Customer Instance - or some other from Entity or Customer inheriting Instances - on a different way. 
My Problem is, that I want to have just a single List to store these listeners. My idea was to create it in the Superclass Entity "Entity". But i cant use the Basetype of Listener "EntityListener" because then I can not call the methods from its Child Interfaces.

How can I just create a single List to store all Listeners. But the Type stored in this list should depend on what Subclass is used? Is that possible at all with my design pattern?

This is important, because I want to expand the hierarchy to other Classes.

A solution i tried was, that i created void addCustomerListener(CustomerListener listener) in the Customer Class, but this produces the same problem.

Comment: Define a generic `class Entity<L extends EntityListener>`, and then the list as `List<L>`

Comment: @Lino.  I think you meant List<L>

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I am getting the same error.

Comment: @WJS didn't I write that?

Comment: @Lino Ships in the night.  FIrst it was List<E>  you must have changed it while I had an old page on my screen.

Comment: @WJS I first wrote `List<E>` jep, but changed it later, sadly (or gladly) comments don't automatically refresh

Comment: Worked. But in my setters i have to check if its really a CustomerListener, or not.

Answer (score 1):

As Lino said in the comments, you need to generify your Entity class.

```
class Entity<L extends EntityListener> {
    protected List<L> listenerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addEntityListener(L listener) {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }

}

class Customer extends Entity<CustomerListener> {

}

interface EntityListener {
    void nameChanged(String name);
}

interface CustomerListener extends EntityListener {
    void businessUnitChanged(String businessUnit);

    void companyChanged(String company);

    void positionChanged(String position);
}
```

However, I'd choose a different option, e.g. going for a `CustomerService` and let the service accept and notify the listeners, so you can decouple the logic(observing/listening) from your domain classes.